# Choosing between activity and fragments (showing map)

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have three screens looks exactly same with different set of data loaded on them.
What design pattern shall i use for it.

Tab1,2,3 also loads different data (Loading from `database`).

- One `activity` and different `fragments` loading data accordingly.
- Three `activities` using same `layout`.
- Plane simple three `activities`. (Or more for tabs too - not sure)

[image]

Comment: It should be in One Activity, different Fragments, Simple and Short !!!

Comment: will need different `fragments` for tabs too...right. the tabs part is confusing for me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what your data is, but is there a reason you can't just cache the data in say, a content provider? Then you could use one activity, one fragment and just have listeners to load different data from the provider.

Comment: Then I'd recommend just loading data directly into your current fragment. If they layout is exactly the same, I don't see a need to make new ones.